# Is URL wrong?Why is bower_components missing?

Tags: angularjs, bower

Now I am making Angular JS app.No error is shown in terminal, but by using Google's verification, many errors are shown in console like
[image: many error]

I wrote in  html file like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/selectize/dist/css/selectize.css" />
```

so I think href cannot be found in program, for example `href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css"`

bower_components is under User directory so I added `User/` to href, it is like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="User/bower_components/selectize/dist/css/selectize.css" />
```

However,same error happens.How can I fix this?I think url is wrong, but another thing cause error?

Comment: Have you added any base href for your application?

Comment: @Vivz Is it meaning whether I wrote base href somewhere on my app or not?

Comment: Yes in your index file, have you given any base href?

Comment: @Vivz No.Is it needed?How can I write it?Should it be written in full directory?

Comment: It is not needed. It can cause the above problems, so I was just wondering if you had put any invalid base href on your index file. Maybe you could post your project structure. The urls are not pointing to the correct files.

Comment: are you referencing correct path for bower_components ?